# How does multiple integral change into terms multiplying each other in convolution theorem of Laplace?

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

[image]

In the steps of the proofs highlighted below, how does a multiple integral changes in to multiplication of two integral. This is only possible if V is independent of u, but as it turns out V = t - u, so they are not actually independent.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution leads to a definite integral 
$$
I = \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-sv} f(v) \, dv
$$
which does not depend on $u$.

The prior integral
$$
I_0 = \int\limits_u^\infty e^{-s(t-u)} f(t-u) \, dt
$$
seems to depend on $u$, but it is not as $I$ shows.

Comment: But v is clearly dependent on u

Comment: $v$ is derived from $u$, but that $I$ is not dependent on $u$ anymore, $v$ is just an integration variable.